# Shortest paths graph

Tags: algorithms

Given a directed graph $G$, edge weights for each edge, source vertex $s$ and $d[v]$ for each vertex in the graph (the distance from $s$ to $v$), I need to find an algorithm that builds the shortest paths graph.

I was thinking of going on edges by BFS, but then how can I know which edge should be in the tree and how to check that the $d[v]$ for each vertex is true?

Comment: What is a "shortest paths graph"?

Comment: @Juho He probably means a tree which is a sub-graph of $G$, where any edge $(u, v)$ is present only if it is on the shortest path from $s$ to $v$. Informally, he probably wants the collection of shortest paths (1 path per vertex) in the form of a tree. But you are right, the OP needs to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Thre are multiple algorithms already developed like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), [Bellman-Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm) or [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

The problem you face is also well described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Maybe there is something specific about your assignment like memory or time complexity?

Comment: sorry i meant the shortest path graph... I dont know if this is exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, there are well known shortest path algorithms. But your problem already has most of the information. Specifically, you already know the shortest path distances $d[v]$ from $s$ for each node $v$. In such a case, you can use a much better algorithm.

By a "shortest paths graph", I think you mean a collection of shortest paths from $s$ to every other vertex $v$. In such a case, you can use a [Depth First Search (DFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) as follows:

- Start the DFS from the source vertex $s$.
- Mark a node visited as soon as you reach it for the first time.
- For every node $u$ visited, do a DFS on all children $v$ of $u$ only if $d[v] = d[u] + w(u, v)$, where $w(u, v)$ is the weight of the edge from $u$ to $v$.
- If a child $v$ of $u$, which obeys the previous condition of distances, has already been visited, it simply means that there are multiple shortest paths from $s$ to $v$, and that you have already selected some other such path which does not go through $u$. In such a case, do *not* include this edge $(u, v)$ in your shortest paths tree/graph. This is because by doing a DFS, you have already selected *all* shortest paths that go through $v$.

Note that this algorithm relies on the following property of a shortest path algorithm: edge $(u, v)$ is on some shortest path to $v$ from $s$ if and only if 
$d[v] = d[u] + w(u, v)$. Therefore, only the shortest paths are taken by the algorithm. Since we ignore a shortest path from $s$ to $v$ through $u$ if and only if $v$ has already been visited, we ensure that all shortest paths are included.

Note that this algorithm is linear in the size of the graph. I mention DFS, since it is much easier to program for such a scenario, and recursion holds the stack implicitly.

However, you can use BFS too for this purpose. Use the same property in the BFS as above, that is:

- Enqueue (and mark visited) only those neighbors $v$ of $u$ which obey the following property: $d[v] = d[u] + w(e, v)$.

Note that if there are multiple shortest paths to some vertex $v$ from $s$, using a DFS or a BFS may give different shortest path trees (though both will be correct). DFS will give a random tree, whereas BFS will give a tree where the shortest path selected would be such that it will also have the minimum number of edges among all shortest paths from $s$ to $v$. Unless you desire such a property, I think a DFS would be much simpler.
See this [Udacity nugget](http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs215/CourseRev/1/Unit/218001/Nugget/223003) for more information about how to compare these algorithms and a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The best algorithm depends on whether $d[v]$ is reliable or not. If it is reliable then you can find the shortest paths graph like this:

```
for each edge e in G:
    if weight[e] + d[origin of e] == d[end of e]:
        include e in the output graph
```

If $d[v]$ is not reliable then [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [the Bellman-Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm) are best, and will also produce the correct values of $d[v]$ as a side effect.

**EDIT**

The graph produced by the above algorithm is not guaranteed to be a tree because of the possibility of equal cost paths. If you need it to be a tree, then you will need to use [Edmonds's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm).

Comment: This algorithm will include *all* parallel shortest paths from the source $s$ to any node $v$. Even though the OP is not very clear, he mentions a tree of edges, which probably indicates he wants a tree, and hence only one shortest path from source to every vertex must be included.